# Rebase only a single folder

Tags: git

I'm working on the client side of a project and my colleagues are working on the server side. I'd to rebase my changes with the master branch, but only those that are on my client side folder as I don't want to mess on my colleagues work. Is that possible?

I've tried with:

```
git checkout master -- <folder>
```

But that overrides all my folder's files, I'd like to have something like the rebase process but just with one folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're only working on the client, how is letting the changes your colleague has already committed and pushed be applied to a different part of the app a problem?

Comment: we're working on the same branch, but in different parts of the project. My idea is just deal with the client side problems that could appear during the rebase.

Comment: Why do you think there's be any *other* conflicts? If you haven't changed that part of the app, and your colleague has already successfully applied all of those commits, why would they fail to apply to your working copy?

Comment: when i do the rebase from master i see conflicts in the server side that I have no idea what's the correct way to solve them, that's my point (sorry for the misunderstanding), I'd like to somehow apply latest changes to my changes and create a new commit with them something like: "ONLY client code has been rebased from master" or so

Comment: @Krishna That is not what .gitignore does

Comment: I don't change the server side code, but when I do a pull, I get the server side changes as we're both working on the same branch, so in the same branch, there're client and server side changes. That's fine so far, but I've tried to do a rebase from master to our branch and then that happened, I see merge conflicts on the server side and I don't want to deal with them as I'm not aware of what the changes are on the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking just at the question, the short answer is: there is no easy way to do that.  Trying to rebase only changes in one directory works against the grain of how git stores data.

Looking at the discussion in comments, it becomes a little clearer what you're trying to accomplish (I think), so maybe we can piece something together.  But do understand, it appears you're in this position because you and your colleague are ignoring git features that would've avoided it.  What I mean is - why are you both working on the same branch if you want to be able to act on your changes independently?

Well, anyway, you have something going on like this

```
... x -- x -- x <--(master)
     \
      F1 -- B1 -- B2 -- F2 -- F3 -- F4 -- B3 <--(branch)
```

I'm assuming, at least, that your changes appear in separate commits from your colleague's changes.  So `F<n>` represents one of your commits, updating the frontend, and `B<n>` represents one of your colleague's commits, updating the backend (server).

If at least that's true - and if your commits don't depend no the `B` commits and vice versa - then you would want an end state like

```
                F1' -- F2' -- F3' -- F4' <--(frontend)
               /
... x -- x -- x <--(master)
     \
      B1' -- B2' -- B3' <--(server)
```

Note that this does still involve rewriting the `B` commits so that the `server` branch doesn't have to keep redundant copies of your changes.  This is likely to be important when the time comes to re-integrate the branches, especially if the rebase of `F` commits generates conflicts.

So what you'd hope for here is that `F` commit changes don't ever conflict with `B` commit changes - which, in your scenario, is plausible at least.

So the first thing is to get a list of commits to be rebased.  That could be done by author name if indeed you wrote all the `F` commits and they wrote all the `B` commits.

```
git rev-list --author=your_name
```

Or it could be done by path if you're 100% sure that your commits - and *only* your commits - affected certain paths.  So you could say

```
git rev-list -- path/to/frontend/code
```

Or you could manually scan throug the entire log (`git log master..branch`) and make note of the commits you want.

Then

```
git checkout branch
git checkout -b frontend
git rebase -i master
```

This will load an editor with a 'todo list' having one entry per commit on `branch`.  Delete the entries for `B` commits from the list, and then save and quit.  You may have to resolve some conflicts, but it should be only for changes you made.  Then you would have

```
                F1' -- F2' -- F3' -- F4' <--(frontend)
               /
... x -- x -- x <--(master)
     \
      F1 -- B1 -- B2 -- F2 -- F3 -- F4 -- B3 <--(branch)
```

Then you need to create the server branch.  You want to make sure *not* to move it forward to the `master` tip, so you can't just rebase to `master`; but you can do this:

```
git checkout branch
git checkout -b server
git rebase -i $(git merge-base master HEAD)
```

This time when the todo list comes up you delete the `F` commits.  If there are any conflicts, it means that you and your colleague did in fact have overlapping changes, and you'd have to sort those out; you would not see conflicts between your colleague's work and `master`, because his work is staying put prior to any `master` changes.

Then you have

```
                F1' -- F2' -- F3' -- F4' <--(frontend)
               /
... x -- x -- x <--(master)
    | \
    |  B1' -- B2' -- B3' <--(server)
     \
      F1 -- B1 -- B2 -- F2 -- F3 -- F4 -- B3 <--(branch)
```

and if you want you can then discard the original `branch`

```
git branch -D branch
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it